# Retrieve Cassandra partition data in Apache Spark

Tags: cassandra, apache-spark, pyspark, spark-cassandra-connector

I have my data well organized by partition key on **Cassandra**. I would like to retrieve this data in **Spark** and keep the same partitions.

My goal is to avoid a very large shuffle.

PS : I am using Cassandra 2.1 and Spark 1.5

Comment: You are going to have to elaborate ... By default this is what the Spark Cassandra Connector does.

Comment: @RussS That's what I wanted to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Spark Cassandra Connector reads C* Token Ranges into Spark Partitions. This means all of the values for any given Cassandra Partition key will be in the same Spark Partition.

https://academy.datastax.com/demos/how-spark-cassandra-connector-reads-data